# Is a root the input or the solution for the quadratic formula?

Tags: quadratics

For the quadratic formula, what is a root - is it the numbers you put into it (a, b or c) or is it the answers you get after crunching the numbers (x1, x2)?

Answer (score 0):

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are the [roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_of_a_function) of a quadratic equation.

In general, we say $x$ is a root of a function $f$ if $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers $a,b,c$ in the quadratic polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ are called **coefficients**, any value of $x$ for which the polynomial evaluates to $0$ is called a **root** of the polynomial

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty much unclear. But I will try to answer what it is. 
You have a quadratic equation:

$$ax^2 + bx + c = 0 $$

Here, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are called the **co-efficients** of the equation.

And the quadratic formula gives you two values for $x$ , let's say $x_1$ and $x_2$. These are the **roots** or **solutions** of the quadratic equation, which means that putting these values in place of $x$ in the equation, would satisfy the equation. So in short:

$$a(x_1)^2 + bx_1 + c = 0 $$
$$a(x_2)^2 + bx_2 + c = 0 $$